# PDO Bind Param Trouble

Tags: php, pdo

I'm trying to convert my codes to `PDO` from `mysql_query`, and starting with this function

```
function label_for_field($field_name, $table_name) {
        $table = array();
        // Bind variables to parameters
        $param_array = array(':bundle' => $table_name, ':field_name' => $field_name);
        // Prepare Query Statement
        $query = "SELECT data FROM field_config_instance WHERE bundle = :bundle AND field_name = :field_name";
        $STH = $DBH -> prepare($query);
        // Execute
        $STH -> execute($param_array);

        // Set the fetch mode
        $STH -> setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        while ($row = $STH -> fetch()) {
            $info = unserialize($row -> data);
            $table[] = $info['label'];
        }
        return $table[0];
    }
```

and I'm trying out just output it to see if it works

```
include_once ("includes/connect.php");
include ("includes/functions.php");

echo label_for_field("field_account_number", "account_table");
```

And here's the `connect.php`

```
// Include Constants
require_once ("constants.php");

//Establish Connection
try {
    $DBH = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass);
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $e -> getMessage();
}
```

I don't know if it's because I'm binding the parameters wrong, it just gave me an server error page

"Server error. The website encountered an error while retrieving ......."

Thanks in advance

Comment: @feeela I just edited the question and added additional information about the error

Comment: No, you haven't. Refer to your servers `error.log` to see the actual error…

Comment: @feeela I didn't even know there's a `error.log` till you mentioned it. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead to see if you get valid objects returned from the query.

```
    // Prepare Query Statement
    $query = "SELECT data FROM field_config_instance WHERE bundle = :bundle AND field_name = :field_name";
    $STH = $DBH -> prepare($query);
    $STH->bindValue(":bundle", $table_name);
    $STH->bindValue(":field_name", $field_name);
    $STH->execute();
    $STH->setFetchMode (PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

    $result = $STH->fetchAll();

    var_dump($result);
```

Comment: it works this way, but I don't get why I cannot use the array like I stated in the problem

Comment: @user1301840 in the original with the array, just add a fetchall after the execute and var_dump the result.  Are you getting that far results sent back?

Comment: I did what you say, and it works. But when I put it in as a function, it just doesn't work

Comment: Just figured out what's going on, `$DBH` isn't defined within the function, that's why the connection to the database wasn't even established. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @user1301840 doh!  Always the obvious:)

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the [PDO error mode](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php) to produce exceptions before you can catch them.

In your `connect.php`:

```
try {
    $DBH = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass);
    $DBH->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 
}
```

Then you can have a similar try/catch statement in your function to that of your connection file, and use it to show the error in your development environment.

Comment: I put it there, but it's not changing anything

Comment: It won't on its own; you need a similar try/catch where you run the query too. However, that will only show an error message if the query actually produced an exception. It's possible there is an alternative cause of your server error problem.